# APL Dyalog Nested Array Element Transformations

Tags: arrays, vector, nested, apl, dyalog

I've been using Dyalog APL for a class assignment and I've run across an issue in transforming each element of a nested array.

I have a character array called HOLD which has a variable amount of 7 character long arrays in it. Using a split transformation I can turn it into a nested array of readonly nested arrays, however I need them to be to be character vectors.

I can individually change an element into a character vector with the MIX operator,

```
TEST←↑HOLD[1]  ⍝Test will be a character vector
```

but I can't seem to do this to every single element at the same time.

My best attempt looks like

```
TEST←↑¨HOLD ⍝Test will be a nested array, seemingly identical to hold
```

but this seems to leave each element as readonly character array. How can I preform this operation on every element in HOLD at the same time and get a resulting nested array of only character vectors?

Comment: I'm curious as to what of class uses Dyalog APL... I'm a bit confused by your question. A character array holds characters, not other arrays. An example would be nice.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear, the original character array is just a list of random alphanumeric characters, with every 7 characters starting a new line. For example:

    AIG67QC
    C12TOBL
    W1ZKGG2

I'm not sure how APL handles newlines, but each set of 7 characters is on a newline in my original character array.

Comment: The course is a general programming language class at my university. It's basically an overview of many different languages, and it's a required course for Computer Science majors.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821632/problems-when-trying-to-use-arrays-in-apl-what-have-i-missed) help you?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the "[enlist](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Enlist.htm)"-primitive. It requires [`⎕ML`](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/ml.htm) to be >0, so I'm assigning it within a dfn (to keep scope local): 
`TEST←{⎕ML←1 ⋄ ∊⍵}HOLD`

If your ⎕ML is already >0 (see [status bar](http://help.dyalog.com/16.0/Content/UserGuide/The%20APL%20Environment/Session%20StatusBar.htm)), you can simply do: `TEST←∊HOLD`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///Py0//1HbBHVPdQX1xFwQAcRlqckl@UVARn4akChJrSiBCxarcz3qmwrUUQ2kcnOADEOFR90tCo86uh71bq1VABqnc2gFUPn//wA)

Comment: I think my problem may lie in getting the elements at certain indexes. I tested with your example of foo←'I' 'am' 'a' 'vector' 'of' 'text' 'vectors'. When I set bar←foo[4], it shows the object as a readonly nested array instead of a vector. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Well, it's not exactly "readonly", you can always overwrite it! ;-) In order to get the content of the element AND remove that one level of nesting, do `4⊃foo`. You could also do `∊foo[4]` which looks similar, but is not. Try: `foo[4]←∊'multiple' 'strings'`and experiment with the previous statements! ;-)

Comment: Sorry, typo! I meant "...try `foo[4]←⊂'multiple' 'strings'`