# Dyalog APL - Read from .txt file

Tags: apl, dyalog

i'm new to dyalog APL and i'm struggling to read some input from an .txt file under Windows 10.
The input data has the format: number name newline 
I want to store every line as an array element and in theory the `input←⎕NGET 'input.txt' 1` function i'm using should work just fine.
According to the docs I should get a vector of char vectors as a result. But in my case I just get a scalar.
I'm able to transform the scalar into a vector of chars with `⍕input[1]` but then i have every line in one single vector which is the oposite of what `input←⎕NGET 'input.txt' 1` should have given me.

Did i miss a page or why is the initial function not working as it should do?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#Language/System%20Functions/nget.htm):

> The result R is a 3-element vector comprising `(content) (encoding) (newline)`
> You're only interested in the first element, so the First function (`⊃`) is your friend:

```
input←⊃⎕NGET 'input.txt' 1
```

Comment: Thank you! But now i'm confused. When ⊃ gives you the first element of a vector and indexing like in C input[1] is also possible, why do i get a nested array if i use ⊃input but only a giant scalar if i use input[1]?

Comment: @erbsenhexler Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46834334/5306507) answer your question?

Comment: yes it does. Thank you again